# How to fix "This element cannot be renamed" in Typescript?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, eslint, intellisense, tslint

What causes VS code editor to decide my typescript symbol cannot be renamed? I'm trying to change the symbol with the `f2` key and run into the error message "This element cannot be renamed".

[image]

Although on some of my other projects the symbol is allowed to be renamed via f2.
As I'm trying to troubleshoot this issue, I'm hoping to learn more about the issue so I can know if it is package issue, vscodes config or if having similar symbol names in a monorepo project can cause this issue?

---

```
"@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "4.3.0",
"@typescript-eslint/parser": "4.3.0",
"typescript": "4.1.5"
```

Comment: I think "symbol" might not be a good term to use here, as it [has a different meaning](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol) in JavaScript/TypeScript.  Maybe... "identifier"?

Comment: @jcalz Thanks, I called it symbol as f2 command for vscode keyboard shortcuts called it "Rename Symbol"

Answer (score -1):

I don't know if it will help anyone or not

Although I don't program in TS, there was a situation with me when I created a file in VSC, but did not specify the file extension.  In this case, VSC cannot fix the variable with F2.

Comment: What do you mean by "VLC"? As far as I know, that is a media player that does not know anything about variables

Comment: This is my mistake. I wrote VLC instead of VSC) It was about Visual Studio Code

Answer (score -4):

Same problem happened to me but instead of using just F2. I used now ctrl+shift+L this will rename all the occurrences in program. It's not good as F2 command but it will do your work almost.

Comment: This is not an answer. Rename all occurrences in a file is the same as search and replace. It is a `dumb` tool and will rename everything that looks the same, be it a code element (variable, property, field, class, etc.) or just a simple string occurrence somewhere that looks the same.